# How to make a custom select the data using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to show data to `RecyclerView`. It's just that I have trouble doing custom in select data.

The case is I want to display data `whose` ID `is not` the same as the `ID of the device currently logged in`.

[image]

Now if I get the data from server, it will show `two` data. It should be just `one` data. Because I dont want user id is currently logged in to appear

My **UserActivity :**

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView mUsersList;
    private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
    private CircleImageView mDisplayImage;
    private ProgressBar mLoading;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_users);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        Toast.makeText( UsersActivity.this, "MY_LOG : " + currentUser.getUid().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("User List");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDisplayImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
        mLoading = (ProgressBar) findViewById( R.id.loading_activity_user );

        mUsersDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mUsersDatabase.keepSynced( true );

        mUsersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
        mUsersList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mUsersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UsersViewHolder>(
                Users.class,
                R.layout.users_single_layout,
                UsersViewHolder.class,
                mUsersDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final UsersViewHolder usersViewHolder, Users users, int position) {

                final String user_id = getRef(position).getKey();

                usersViewHolder.setDisplayName(users.getName());
                usersViewHolder.setStatus(users.getStatus());
                usersViewHolder.setThumbImage(users.getThumb_image(), getApplicationContext());

                mUsersDatabase.child( user_id ).addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (dataSnapshot.hasChild( "online" )) {
                            String userOnlineStatus = dataSnapshot.child( "online" ).getValue().toString();
                            if(userOnlineStatus.equals( "Online" )) {
                                usersViewHolder.setOnlineIcon( "Online" );
                            } else {
                                usersViewHolder.setOnlineIcon( "Offline" );
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                } );

                usersViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent profile_intent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        profile_intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
                        startActivity(profile_intent);

                    }
                });

                if (position == getItemCount() - 1) {
                    mLoading.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
                    mUsersList.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
                }
            }
        };

        mUsersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
        mUsersList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    }

    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setDisplayName(String name) {
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
            userNameView.setText(name);
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            TextView statusView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
            statusView.setText(status);
        }

        public void setThumbImage(final String thumb_image, final Context ctx) {
            final CircleImageView userImageView = (CircleImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);

            Picasso.with(ctx)
                    .load(thumb_image)
                    .networkPolicy( NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE )
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_profile)
                    .into( userImageView, new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError() {
                            Picasso.with(ctx)
                                    .load(thumb_image)
                                    .resize(80, 80)
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.no_profile)
                                    .into(userImageView);
                        }
                    } );
        }

        public void setOnlineIcon(String online_status) {
            ImageView userOnlineView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById( R.id.user_single_online_icon );
            if (online_status.equals( "Online" )) {
                userOnlineView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
            } else {
                userOnlineView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
            }
        }
    }

}
```

With that code I easily display it into `RecyclerView` on the screen.

And I get a Current ID with :

```
currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

How do I modify `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to use `not like command`?

For the results shown are : Retrieve all data in `Users` child, but `don't include` current logged user data.